# Access AWS resources from external non aws entities without IAM Access keys

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying find out the best way to access aws resources from external non-aws resources (Azure/GCP) without using IAM Access Keys, as they are hard to manage and not very secure to use.

Comment: What is "not secure to use"?  Having any external system, you have to maintain the credentials somewhere somehow. The same way you may manage  and secure the aws credentials (e. g. in a KeyVault). At the end - the client needs to be authenticated

Comment: Not secure because you have to make sure the credentials are secure and make sure nobody else has access to them. But i think more than secure it will be a hassle to maintain all these Access Keys if the number of User's increase.

Comment: If you're trying to supply individual users with AWS credentials then use [identity federation](https://aws.amazon.com/identity/federation/) which can supply them with temporary (STS) credentials.

Comment: Where it comes to using aws from an external environment, static access keys are more used for the service accounts. When you need separate credentials for individual users, then using identity federation (as already mentioned) by AWS SSO or Cognito can be better option. The users will get ephemeral credentials according to their roles. Maybe you could edit the question and describe the use case in more details

Comment: @RohitSarkar Are these credentials for use from your _own_ resources in Azure/GCP, or is it for use by your users/customers?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - Credentials will be used by clients to access AWS services/resources in my aws account.

Comment: In general, permanent AWS credentials should only be given to your own staff members or to your own software systems that need to communicate with AWS services. 'Users' should be authenticated through another mechanism and can then be given _temporary_ AWS credentials once they login. These temporary credentials can be given restricted rights based upon the user's needs.

Comment: @jarmod

With your approach can users login via AWS Account also or they can login with Amazon account only?

Comment: @ParthMahida not sure I fully understand your question. My earlier comment relates to [identity federation](https://aws.amazon.com/identity/federation/) i.e. using a non-AWS Identity Provider (e.g. Google, Facebook, Amazon.com, Apple) to authenticate users and thereby authorizing them for access to AWS.

Comment: @jarmod What if I wants to authenticate AWS users and then access AWS resources in external web application based on his roles?

Comment: @ParthMahida by AWS users, do you mean IAM users? IAM users can have two different types of credentials - one (username/password) for logging into the AWS console and the other (access key/secret key) for API use. There's no way for you to authenticate an IAM username/password afaik (only the AWS console can do this), and if your user supplies access key/secret key then that inherently authorizes them.